# UIImage is not displaying

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, ios11, ios12

I know it's a silly question. But I am not finding a way to solve this.
Image icon is located in Image assets (i.e. Assets.xcassets). 
It is being displayed if I run the application from Xcode (i.e. in debug mode). 
But it is not being displayed if I install the application from TestFlight (i.e. Release mode).

Here is my code for that.

somewhere in ViewDidLoad()

```
arriCon = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"home_icon",@"s_Internammatches_icon",@"InternalRating",@"s_tournaments_icon",@"s_EmailManagement_icon",@"s_Canteen_icon",@"Meeting_icon",@"s_event_icon",@"s_stats_icon",@"ic_poll",@"s_ourclub_icon",@"Album_icon",@"s_setting_icon", nil];
```

and somewhere in viewForHeaderInSection()
 (yeah, I've multiple headers in `UITableView` and in that, I'm displaying image)

```
headerView.imgiCon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[arriCon objectAtIndex:section]];
```

Comment: Ohh, yes All other images are being displayed from that "Assets.xcassets"

Comment: ensure if you get value in [UIImage imageNamed:[arriCon objectAtIndex:section]]

Comment: Already checked that on debugging mode, If I didn't getting value then how will be display in debugging mode?

Comment: check once your images are 1.x, 2.x 3.x correctly as well as check with names space once

Comment: yes they are in correct form as in 1x, 2x and 3x

Comment: add like this in array  @"home_icon.png"

Comment: @karthikeyan -  the image taken from assests

Comment: May has something difference between your debug and release mode. You can try to double check it

Comment: Didn't add the condition for debugging and release, and there are no any option for same in Assets.xcassets AFAIK

Comment: When you drag the image to your project make sure it is copied to your targets